# Proportionally editing the highlighted area

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, image, faces, blend-files

I'm in the process if trying to create a screen for a project im working on but Im having trouble of proportionally editing.

I just want the highlighted areas to be edited, so that the highlighted areas will have a smooth round bump on the top like a screen some sort, where It basically arches across the top in a smooth and seamless way like the picture below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

That can be something like this:

[image]

Start with a half cube (cut in half in Z axis).

Flatten it in Z.

Stretch it in X.

Inset the top face.

Add a loop cut along the X axis.

Then another loop cut along Y axis and bevel this last (3 cuts).

Tune the curve aspect grabbing up the top/inside vertices.

Tune the corners to adjust left/right half circle shape.

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

You should begin with a very simple topology like this one:

[image]

If you want the slight slope, lift the face:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to have a rounder shape:

[image]

If it needs the faces all around, extrude down, bevel the edge a bit:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, but im not trying to change the shape of the object I just want to lift the highlighted region to give it a hump while keeping the shape

Comment: invert the selection, make the edges invisible, lift the center of the top faces with the Proportional Editing on?